# Boundary estimates for Neumann derivative of solution to Laplacian equation with Dirchlet boundary data

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth domain. Consider the following Laplacian equation with Dirichlet boundary condition.
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\Delta u=0\quad &\mbox{in $\Omega$}\\
u=g\quad &\mbox{on $\partial \Omega$.}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
By maximal principle, if $g=0$, then $u\equiv 0$ in $\Omega$, and hence $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}=0$ on $\partial \Omega$.

My question is, if $g$ is close to $0$, say in the sense that $\sup_{\partial \Omega}|g|$ is very small, then is it true that $|\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}|$ is also very small on $\partial \Omega$ in any sense? Any ideas or comments would be really appreciated!

Comment: For what it's worth, this is known as the Dirichlet-to-Neumann map.

Comment: @LeoMoos, Could you provide any details, or given a reference?

Comment: Another name is the Poincaré–Steklov operator. Roughly: $\partial u / \partial \nu$ will be one degree less smooth compared to $g$. So roughly: you need $g$ with small $C^1$ norm in order to have $\partial u/\partial \nu$ uniformly small. A rigorous statement may involve spaces of Hölder continuous functions (or Hölder–Zygmund spaces). Unfortunately, I do not know a good introductory text.